# Solspace Rating - where do rating comments go?

Tags: solspace, comments, solspace-rating

I'm using `Rating:Comments` and `Rating:Comment_Form` for the first time. I've successfully set up the form and comments display loop, and submitted my first test comment. I'm submitting comments with a "closed" status status to I can approve them before they show up.

My question is, **where do I find these comments in the EE CP so I can moderate them and change their status to open?**

They are not listed anywhere in the Rating module tabs or as regular EE comments! Am I missing something?

I've made my comments loop display closed comments and I can confirm the comment was saved and shows up there. So it's there somewhere I just don't see any part of the user interface that allows me to see the comment or change its status.

EE 2.7.2
Rating 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rating comments are stored in the exp_rating_reviews table. There is no moderation tools at this time, but we hope to add this in future releases.

Comment: Oh bummer. Not useful to me if it can't be moderated - or at least viewed in the CP. I guess we'll have to wait until a later version to implement this.

Comment: is this still the case with solspace ratings? comments/ratings cannot be moderated?

Comment: Please see http://www.solspace.com/docs/rating/change_log/#v3.3.0 "_Added front and back-end editing and deletion of Rating Comments_"